# Not able to build dll to tridion content manager using Tcmupload assembly

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We have migrated from 5.3 version to Tridion 2011 SP1

In compound templating setup, we have created one project called "CommonFunctions" which contains functions which are used frequently throughout the website.

This cs file is built to tridion content manager and we are trying to reference it in other project using
Add Exixting Item > CommonFunctions.cs > Add as link

But when i try to build my project(in which commonFunctions cs file is referenced) it gives me following error:

Cannot generate a template with name CommonFunctions since a generated template created for another assembly template is already present.

Can anyone help in this?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your CommonFunctions class implement ITemplate? If so then this is why you're seeing the error. Doing so means that, when uploaded, Tridion will try to create a TBB for it, giving you the situation where you have a naming conflict. What's in the class? It should either be help functions or a "template" (TBB), but not both. At least, not if you want to reuse your existing functionality in this way.

You have several options as I see it. The first would be to upload the new assembly to a different folder than the one that is currently in use. The second would be to copy the class to your new project and rename it. The third would be to separate your helper functions from the TBB class in to one that doesn't implement ITemplate, which you could then reference as you're currently trying from your new project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..We have considered 3rd option in our implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Reason is very straight forward, if you go with the error message. You are trying to create two TBB's with same name(CommonFunctions).
I am suggesting you either to alter your already existing TBB or rename the new one.